# Optimized solution for longest common subsequence

Tags: algorithm, optimization, lcs

Which algorithm is the most optimized and efficient for finding the longest common subsequence (strings longer than 400 characters)?

Comment: Dynamic Programming solution is most efficient in general.  But in some certain circumstance, like Biosequences Alignment, there are custom algorithm in these fields. Few algorithm works at any time. So in what circumstance and what efficiency do you pursue

Comment: This is a good start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem. But if you say 'Optimized' what criteria do you want to optimize for? Memory usage, parallelizability, speed, ...

Comment: @MrSmith42 I need the fastest algorithm

Comment: The fastest known algorithms all take at least O(nm) time in the worst case.  If you know something about the strings, e.g. that very few characters occur more than once, or that the two input strings are very similar (have small edit distance), then some faster algorithms can be used.